# /data/anr/traces.txt is not accessible in program since Android N

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, android-7.0-nougat

I used to collect ANR info by reading and analysing /data/anr/traces.txt programmatically. It works very well before Android N.

On Android N, "/data/anr/traces.txt" is NOT accessible.

```
    File anrFile = new File("/data/anr/traces.txt");
    if (anrFile.exists()) {
        boolean read = anrFile.canRead();  //always FALSE
    }
```

My question:

1. How can my app access traces.txt on Android N ?
2. How can my app get its ANR info on Android N ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is an Android N specific issue as it appears to be more generic. **The directory /data/anr or the files in this directory are often readable only by the root user. And thus, when devices is not rooted, we can't get ANR from the files**.

However, from the Android documentation ([bug-report adb documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html#bugreportadb)), you can receive the bugreports using this adb command line:

```
adb bugreport E:\Reports\MyBugReports
```

The final argument is the path where you want the bugreport to be copied on your local computer.

Comment: I think I did understood your question: I have explained why the file is not readable and gave you an alternative. On older Android (depends on manufacturer) it has been possible to read/access the files, but it's becoming more and more restricted with newer Android versions. I do understand that you don't like the answer, but I don't see it wrong! ;)